# Is it possible for this IF statement to be 1 line of code, instead of 5?

Tags: ruby, if-statement, rake

I have the following logic to determine which `eval` query to execute..

```
docker_version=%x[docker version -f {{.Server.Version}}].gsub(/[^0-9,.]/, "")

if docker_version < '17.06'
  query="eval $(aws ecr get-login --region us-west-2)"
else
  query="eval $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-west-2)"
end
sh "#{query}"
```

Is it possible for the `if` statement to be `1` line of code instead of `5`?

Comment: ternary operator?

Comment: How do I go about doing that? I'm new to Ruby / Rake

Comment: In Ruby, you can (almost) always replace newlines with semicolons. Sometimes you need to use a keyword instead, sometimes you don't need anything. It is always possible to write everything in one line. Whether that is a good idea, that is an entirely different question, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a ternary operator:

```
query = docker_version < '17.06' ?
        "eval $(aws ecr get-login --region us-west-2)" :
        "eval $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-west-2)"
```

Using string concatenation we can tidy this up even more:

```
query = "eval $(aws ecr get-login " +
        (docker_version < '17.06' ? "--region us-west-2)" : "--no-include-email --region us-west-2)")
```

Comment: Could this be used with String Concatenation?

Comment: I think the answer could be 1 line by using a ? : inside the string because the strings are so similar (eg. `eval $(aws ecr get-login docker_version < 17.06 ? --no-include-email : "" --region us-west-2)`  I'm just not sure how to do it.

Comment: @TheAuzzieJesus I updated but it still doesn't fit on one line.  Actually, I prefer the first version because it is easier to read in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible for the `if` statement to be `1` line of code instead of `5`?

Newlines are never necessary in Ruby, you can always remove them:

```
if docker_version < '17.06' then query="eval $(aws ecr get-login --region us-west-2)" else query="eval $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-west-2)" end
```

Personally, I don't understand this obsession with "writing everything in 1 line", but you asked for it, and here it is. I don't find it more readable at all.

Answer (score 0):

String concatenation is absolutely a good idea, but it will make little confusion especially for beginners. So for better readability you can make use of string interpolation like below,

```
query = "eval $(aws ecr get-login #{docker_version < '17.06' ? '--region us-west-2' : '--no-include-email --region us-west-2'})"
```

I think you can also move the common option region to outside the ternary oprator,

```
query = "eval $(aws ecr get-login --region us-west-2 #{docker_version < '17.06' ? '' : '--no-include-email'})"
```